# Installing an older version of postgres to run pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

I have a data directory on my system installed by an older version of Postgres (9.1) that is incompatible with 9.2. After I ran these commands..

```
which psql /usr/local/bin/psql

which postgres /usr/local/bin/postgres
```

I was told that my packaging system might not support multiple installs and the  simplest solution for me is to install 9.1 again run pg_dump

Therefore, I uninstalled  9.2.3, after which running

```
'which postgres' returned nothing and 'which psql' returns /usr/bin/psql
```

I read on SO that I could find version directories by running `brew search postgres`, which would maybe give me a response like

```
postgresql
homebrew/versions/postgresql8    homebrew/versions/postgresql9
```

However, I didn't get a version directory. I got this
    brew search postgres
    postgres-xc   postgresql

Can anyone tell me how I might install the older version of postgres and get rid of the data directory created by 9.1

Comment: You might be able to use `pg_upgrade` instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks, for pg_upgrade, i couldn't figure out where to find the values on my system that go in the options specified in these instructions: pg_upgrade -b oldbindir -B newbindir -d olddatadir -D newdatadir [option...]    http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgupgrade.html

Comment: ah, never mind, you'll still need the old binaries to use `pg_upgrade`. BTW, any installation system that says `postgresql8` and `postgresql9` is *totally wrong* and should be avoided. It should be `postgresql84`, `postgresql90`, `postgresql91`, `postgresql92`, etc. Upgrading the user silently from 9.1 to 9.2 is, as you've discovered, a really stupid thing for a package manager to do, it should install the two in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it very complicated to get the various versions of Postgresql installed in order to run pg_dump. Therefore, I removed every trace of 9.1. and 9.2 from my system after which I reinstalled 9.2. Now it's working.